# Win32 Window Styles Overlap Issue

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-style-flags

I have two listboxes windows created by:

```
_objectList = CreateWindow("LISTBOX", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD | LBS_SORT, 5, 50, 10, 50, _windowParent, NULL, _windowInstance, 0);
_resourceList = CreateWindow("LISTBOX", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD | LBS_SORT, 5, 50, 10, 50, _windowParent, NULL, _windowInstance, 0);

ShowWindow(_objectList, 1);
ShowWindow(_resourceList, 0);
```

They're positioned inside a TabControl box, and when I click a tab, I want to show one/hide the other. I'm doing this with:

```
//In the message proc function
if(uMsg == WM_NOTIFY)
{
    if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TCN_SELCHANGE)
    {
        if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->hwndFrom == _tabControl.GetWindowHandle())
        {
            int index = SendMessage(_tabControl.GetWindowHandle(), TCM_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            _tabControl.showTab(index); //this function will call the ShowWindow(); to show only the tab I'd like to display
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the listbox looks when I first run the code (the ObjectList to the right):
[Listbox Properly Showing http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v204/Shakazahn/ListboxOK_zpsee5c62b9.jpg](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v204/Shakazahn/ListboxOK_zpsee5c62b9.jpg)

This is when I click the tab:
[Listbox Got Ugly All of a Sudden http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v204/Shakazahn/ListboxNotOK_zps5d05a019.jpg](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v204/Shakazahn/ListboxNotOK_zps5d05a019.jpg)

And if I click to show the first Listbox, I also get:
[First Listbox Got Infected as Well http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v204/Shakazahn/ListboxNotOK2_zpsc1dca19a.jpg](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v204/Shakazahn/ListboxNotOK2_zpsc1dca19a.jpg)

I tried changing some of the window Styles but nothing worked, also, I don't have a clue why this is happening... any fixes for this?

**edit**: After some tests, I found out that this is happening because both Listboxes are children of the mainWindow, not the tabControl window.
If I set the parentWindow of both to the tabControl, they display fine, but I was having issues with window grandchildren and lots of subclassing, so I'm making all windows children of my main window.
How can I fix this display issue?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style on both listboxes and the tab control, and make sure the z-order is such that the two listboxes are drawn AFTER the tab.

Comment: I put the WS_CLIPSIBLINGS in all of them, and the listboxes disappeared. I haven't set any z-order, but I created them in the order TabControl -> ObjectList -> TextureList. Should I change it with SetWindowPos() or was it supposed to work like this already?